# appendChild() not accepting passed string parameter as an argument?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

My code is meant to add another paragraph `<p>hello</p>` under the 2 existing ones after the "New" button is clicked.

The error must be in the passing of the value from `onclick` to the function or to the `createTextNode` or to `appendChild()` (not being the right data type to be used properly in the function etc). I know this because the function itself works fine without having to pass a parameter to `createTextNode()` and just typing a string instead.

```
<div id="div1">
    <p id="p1">This is a paragraph.</p>
    <p id="p2">This is another paragraph.</p>
</div>

<script>
    function saveSelection(selection) {
        var para = document.createElement("p3");
        var node = document.createTextNode(selection);
        para.appendChild(node);
        var element = document.getElementById("div1");
        element.appendChild(para);
    }
</script>

<button type="button" onclick="saveSelection("hello")">New</button>
```

*Sidenote:If your curious, the broader goal is to eventually write a program that can resemble [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g2C0g.png). Obviously, I plan on exploiting `appendChild` and `removeChild`, and if you know of a more appropriate method to point me towards would be greatly appreciated.*

Comment: [`createElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement) takes the name of the tag you wish to create, not its `id`. So, you'd want to pass in "p", not "p3". you can set the id later using [`setAttribute`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not parsing correctly

```
onclick="saveSelection("hello")"
```

it should be

```
onclick="saveSelection('hello')"
```

and then here

```
var para = document.createElement("p3");
```

the element should be `p` rather than `p3`

see a demo below

```js
function saveSelection(selection) {
  var para = document.createElement("p");
  var node = document.createTextNode(selection);
  para.appendChild(node);
  var element = document.getElementById("div1");
  element.appendChild(para);
}
```

```html
<div id="div1">
  <p id="p1">This is a paragraph.</p>
  <p id="p2">This is another paragraph.</p>
</div>
<button type="button" onclick="saveSelection('hello')">New</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are making very simple mistake in your code while passing value.

Instead of double quotes(" "), use single quotes(' ').

Use `'hello'` instead of `"hello"`

Simple!

Answer (score 0):

Watch out for double double-quotes. Change "hello" to single-quotes.

```
<button type="button" onclick="saveSelection('hello')">New</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
document.createElement("p3");
```

should be

```
document.createElement("p");
```

and

```
"saveSelection("hello")"
```

should be

```
"saveSelection('hello')"
```